# Zuul throwing 404 No meesage Available error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have my below app (microservices) which is successfully registered to Eureka server.I t has below Rest end point

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("v1/base/")
public class PersonController {

    @PostMapping
    @RequestMapping(value="/personid")
    public ResponseEntity< ?> getPersonList(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("All person list");
    }
```

The properties file for person-application

```
eureka:
  instance:
    appname: person-application
  client:
    enabled: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

My zuul server yml file config is  is .

```
  server:
        port:9000
        servlet:
         contextPath: /zuulapp
    
   zuul:
      routes:
         person:
            path: /v1/base/**
            serviceId: person-application
```

When i call hit the rest point localhost:9000/zuulapp/person/personid i get the below error.How do i resolve this error

```
{
   "timestamp":"2019-10-08T12:42:09.479+0000",
   "status":404,
   "error":"Internal Server Error",
   "message":"No Message available"
   "path" : "/zuulapp/person/personid"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the registered path in the zuul of the application is "/v1/base/**"

try this one: delete the contextpath properties then replace it with zuul.prefix properties.

```
  server:
        port:9000
      
    
   zuul:
      prefix: /zuulapp
      routes:
         person:
            path: /person/**
            serviceId: person-application
```

Now try checking this endpoint:

localhost:9000/zuulapp/person/v1/base/personid

try this in the controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/base/")
public class PersonController {

    @GetMapping(value="/personid")
    public ResponseEntity< ?> getPersonList(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("All person list");
    }
```

Comment: "ipersonid" is a typo while typing question.Corrected it.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue yet? try the change path. hope it helps.

Comment: I edited my answer try the latest change. you can give an update. thanks